# How Do I Stop a Web Service Method That Has Been Executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service that gets calls via jquery, it can take up to 60 seconds for data to be returned:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    url: "WebServices/behData.asmx/noResolutions",
    data: JSON.stringify(param),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var data = response.d;

        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#tblCleanup")) {
            $('#tblCleanup').DataTable().clear().destroy();
        }
    }
})
```

If for some reason I wanted to stop the execution of this method before the data is returned, how would I do it?

I would want the "stoppage" to occur through JQuery or javascript...

Comment: Note that while you can `abort()` the request (as outlined in the duplicate), you cannot immediately stop the server from continuing to process it.

Comment: Thank You kind sir...is there something I need to do to mark this question as closed or answered or duplicate?

Comment: Glad to help. The question is already closed, so there's nothing you need to do.